# titanium alloy global functions

Tags: mobile, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

i have a question, are the global functions set in alloy.js runs every time the app is started or every time a new window is open?

because i actually would like to create a unique user id for the user and assign it a global variable so it can be used through the app but i ain't sure if it will re-create and re-assign the generated user id whenever the app tries to open another window or will it use same user_id that the app generated after instantiating the mobile app.

hope someone could answer me. >.<

Comment: Are these functions you defined in alloy.js or are you referring to something deeper down in the Titanium SDK and wondering how a window was created?  If they were functions you defined there, I'd throw an alert('OMG THIS JUST RAN') in it so I could see what happens.  I didn't think functions in alloy.js were run unless you specifically called them so I might be confused about what you are asking about or unfamiliar with that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in alloy.js will run every time the app is loaded, and they will load near the beginning of the execution of the app. So the answer is NO, your unique ID will NOT be re-created every time a new window opens.

From the Titanium DOC:

> The initializer file app/alloy.js can be used to execute some code near the beginning of the application's lifecycle. The contents of this file will be executed right before the initial index.js controller is loaded, allowing you to execute code before any UI components are loaded and to override builtin Alloy functions before they are executed.

Also, here's an example of how to run a function and store the result in a global variable (your unique_id function would work the same way):

```
Alloy.Globals.myId = function(){
   var id = (CODE TO GENERATE ID)
   return id;
}
```